# Can I notch the top of floor joists for plumbing drains?

Tags: bathroom, vanity, drains

I demo'd my bathroom yesterday and under the vanity the drains are above the subfloor for over a foot. Of course I bought a vanity already that has the feet that you can see under so this is a problem for me.

It looks like they did not go through the baseplate of the wall because the drains feed into the main sewer line that is in the next floor joist bay. Can I drill through the top 3rd of the floor joist (2x10) here and rerun the pipes under the subfloor?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you planning on demo'ing the floor and walls anyway?  If so, you'll expose the venting (if any) and framing and you can add pictures that will make it easier to solve your problem.   If you were not planning further demo, and if this drain has always worked well, no siphon problems, you should leave it and replace or modify your new vanity.

Comment: Probably not, but you haven't told us much at all about the _framing_, which is the critical information here. Please revise to add detail. Also take the [tour].

Comment: I can demo more if there is a chance of making this work. If everyone thinks there is no possible solution no matter the demo then I would leave it and work around

Comment: As for the guidelines, can notches only be in the bottom or top 1/3 of the height as well as the first or last 3rd of the length for floor joists?